# Change view when clicking alert button not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

Good day,

This is my code:

```
@IBAction func logOutAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        try! FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Sure?", message: "Are you sure you want to log out?", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

    let defaultAction2 = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction2)

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    let VC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginscreen") as! ViewController //The file that controls the view

    self.presentViewController(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

As you can see I want to log out the user when pressing the logout button. When the user clicks logout a UIalert popsup asking if they are sure they want to log out, but when I click okay it doesn't switch back to the loginscree ViewController.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the last two lines represent the view that you want to present, then you have to execute this code inside the handler of the "Yes" button action:

```
let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default, handler: { _ in
    let VC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginscreen") as! ViewController //The file that controls the view

    self.presentViewController(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
})

alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to logout after somebody click "Yes"

```
    let yesActionHandler = { (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        let VC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginscreen") as! ViewController //The file that controls the view
        self.presentViewController(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default, handler: yesActionHandler)
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
```